# Как сделать всплывающее окно в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Хочу сделать всплывающее окно при написании какой-либо команды. Подскажите как можно сделать, желательно куском кода. за любую помощь буду благодарен.

P.s. Я имею ввиду pop up, всплывающее окно наподобие этого
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если речь за подсказки как в bot father то там это и делается. заходите в меню своего бота затем выбираете "Edit bot" -> "Edit Commands" и дальше как написано там в примере заполняете список команд.

Comment: нет, я имел ввиду pop up, всплывающие окна

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо воспользоваться `bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id, text, show_alert=True)`.

В качестве примера :

```
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(self, message: types.Message):
    inline_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)   
    
    inline_keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='alert', callback_data='alert'))
    await message.answer("choice: ", reply_markup=inline_keyboard)
    
@dp.callback_query_handler(text=['alert'])
async def alert(self, callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback.id, text='your text', 
                                        show_alert=True)
```